# Order of an element in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

I was wondering the order of an element $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$
For $z=a+bi$, would it be the absolute value/modulus? That is,

$$|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

Thanks

Comment: That's not what I asked about. I am asking about the order of an element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If you see $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ as a multiplicative group, there will be elements of finite order. Those of the form $z=e^{i2\pi n/m}, m\neq 0$ obviously have finite order. Numbers with norm $\neq 1$ will have infinite order. One could also prove that if $r\in\mathbb{R}^\times-\mathbb{Q}^\times$, then $e^{ir2\pi}$ has infinite order.

Comment: OP, you should try to interrogate your thought process here: why did you think the order of an element in $\mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ would be its modulus?

Comment: You use the word "order". This word is, unfortunately, used for many things in mathematics. Could you expand a bit on what exactly you would want to use this order for? What purpose do you want it to fulfill? What properties do you want it to have? What operations do you want it to cooperate nicely with?

Comment: To expand on the comment of @Arthur, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(mathematics)) to see the many different ways that the word "order" is used in mathematics. Which of those is the one you are asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element $z\in\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$ has finite order if and only if it is an $n$th root of unity; that is, $z^n=1$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. This implies $\lvert z\rvert=1$ and so $z=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. The rest of the nonzero complex numbers have infinite order.